# How can I use document.body to append a table that will be placed in a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html

After I duplicate the table. I want to place this new table in a specific DIV called div1. How do I append the new table to div1?

```
<div 
id="div1">
</div>



var elementz = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1]; //cloning a table
var table = elementz.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td> 
    </tr>
</table>     

<div id='div1'></div>

<script>
    const div1 = document.getElementById('div1')
    const table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    const newTable = table.cloneNode(true);  //cloning a table
    div1.appendChild(newTable);
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```